# Pygame sprites always on top example?

Tags: object, pygame, sprite

I was wondering if someone could give me simple example of how to always draw sprites in pygame on --the top layer-- whilst an animation is being blitted on screen?

The senario I'm trying to solve is having an animated sprite (eg a man walking on the spot) and various other objects passing him, whilst he is still animated.

My solution so far has the animation layering on top of the "passing objects" which is not what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've partially answered your own question here.

It's a matter of organizing  what gets drawn first. Some side-scrolling 2D games use a "layer" solution, in which there is a background layer, a middleground layer, and a foreground layer, and the drawing system renders one layer after another.

I've also seen Pokémon top-down style games simply sort the sprites by their vertical position, so sprites "nearest" to the camera are drawn last, and thus on top of the other sprites.

See how [the current implementation of Scene2D in libGDX](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.java#L665-L696) gives each Actor a z-index property which can later be used to organize Actors into layers.

Answer (score 0):

Just draw your sprites with a [`LayeredUpdates`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates) group:

> **class pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates**
>   *LayeredUpdates is a sprite group that handles layers and draws like OrderedUpdates*.
>   `LayeredUpdates(*spites, **kwargs) -> LayeredUpdates`
>
> You can set the default layer through kwargs using ‘default_layer’ and an integer for the layer. The default layer is 0.
>
> If the sprite you add has an attribute layer then that layer will be used. If the **kwarg contains ‘layer’ then the sprites passed will be added to that layer (overriding the sprite.layer attribute). If neither sprite has attribute layer nor **kwarg then the default layer is used to add the sprites.

and give your sprites the correct `layer` value.